# Trouble mapping a javascript object to vb.net structure

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I am passing a pair of serialized objects into a vb.net webservice.  The first one maps to a known structure, so I am using the structure type in the parameter list of the webservice.  The second object may map to one of 6+ structures.  A field in the first object will tell me which structure to use for the second object once both objects are passed to the webservice.

```
a.template = jQuery('#txtTemplate').val();
a.value1 = jQuery('#txtValue1').val();
b.var1 = jQuery('#txtVar1).val();
b.var2 = jQuery('#txtVar2).val();

Public Structure Atype
    Public template as string
    Public value1 as string
End Type

Public Structure Btype
    Public var1 as string
    Public var2 as string
End Type

Public Structure cType
    Public hours as string
    Public days as string
    Public minutes as string
End Type

<WebMethod()>
Public Function Save(byval aData as Atype, byval miscData as object) as string

If aData.template = "b" then
    'move miscData to Btype
else
    'move miscData to cType
end if
```

I've simplified the structures for this example.  Viewing everything under debug, I am getting into the webservice fine.  aData maps out correctly.  miscData shows the name/value pairs.  I've tried DirectCast and Ctyping the object into the correct struct - both fail with an error.
Any ideas of how to get this to work under vb.net 2.0?  I know I can use a dictionary to read through the name/value pairs, but would prefer to use a structure.

Comment: Update - I admit I'm a little confused with regard to collections, arraylists, dictionaries, etc under vb.net. Under debug, I can reference the name/value pairs as:  miscData.item("var1").toString.  I'm thinking the only way to get this into a structure would involve looping through each key/value pair.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a local rendition of this, but had difficulty getting my 2.0 vb.net web service to reply.  I will tell you my strategy, though.  I would try creating a complex object to return.

Also, I think you need to use classes here instead of Structures. Strings can easily be larger than 16 bytes.

```
var message = {
    yourAtype : {
         value1 : jQuery('#txtValue1').val()
    },
    yourBType : {
         var1 : jQuery('#txtVar1').val(),
         var2 : jQuery('#txtVar2').val()
    },
    yourCType : {
         hours : jQuery('#txtHours').val(),
         days : jQuery('#txtDays').val(),
         minutes : jQuery('#txtMinutes').val()
    }
};

Public Class Atype
    'Public template as string    <--No longer needed
    Public value1 as string
End Class 

Public Class Btype
    Public var1 as string
    Public var2 as string
End Class 

Public Class cType
    Public hours as string
    Public days as string
    Public minutes as string
End Class 

Public Class MessageType
    Public myAType as Atype
    Public myBType as Btype
    Public myCType as cType
End Class

<WebMethod()>
Public Function Save(byval message as MessageType) as string

If Not message.myAType is Nothing
    'do what you need with AType
else if Not message.myBType is Nothing
    'do what you need with BType
else if Not message.myCType is Nothing
    'do what you need with CType
end if
```

Comment: Not quite what I need.  This approach would have me sending (possibly) hundreds of empty fields for non-used templates across the wire.